# React Hook Form watch callback

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-hook-form

As per React Hook Form's documentation, for performance issues, we can consider using a callback. However, it is not very clear how the callback can be used. Can I get some example/reference where this usage would be more clear ?

https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/watch

> This API will trigger re-render at the root of your app or form,
> consider using a callback or the useWatch api if you are experiencing
> performance issues.

**P.S:** For version dependency and me not having control over the same, I cannot consider using "useWatch". So looking at optimizing with "watch" itself.

**UPDATED**

I tried the below syntax for watching form fields. For some reason, it never goes inside the console statements even if I change the form field values.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const subscription = watch((values) => {
        console.log("watch callback :::: " + values);
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, [watch]);
```

Comment: `watch(values => { /* your code goes here */ })`

Comment: Thanks...so I assume values would be array of field's name to watch

Comment: @Konrad : I updated my question with what I tried with the callback function, but for some reason it is not working